# Why is my variable isn't being read inside foreach when I declrared it outside foreach?

Tags: laravel, controller

I'm having a problem with my foreach, it doesn't read the variable I have created in the top.

```
public function checkForPermission($user, $request)
{
    $permission = json_decode($user->role->permission);
    // echo $rolePermission[0]->name;
    // echo $request->path();
    $hasPermission = false;
    $path = $request->path();

    foreach ($permission as $p) {
        if ($p->name == $path) {
            if ($p->read) {
                $hasPermission = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

as you can see in the picture the $hasPermission inside the foreach isn't reading (it should be highlighted). That's why it cannot be change to true even when the User has a permission of read on a specific route/pages.

I have tried \Log::info inside the foreach and still it isn't reading.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Laravel is a PHP framework. You've tagged this question as Javascript.

Comment: I tagged both. what's your problem?

Comment: That the question you've asked seems to have nothing to do with Javascript. Anyways, this doesn't matter now, as the tags have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `return $hasPermission`. It's not highlighted because your IDE knows it's not actually getting used anywhere. You might also want to also `break` when it's set to true, or do an early return there, just to save a few CPU ticks. If that doesn't solve it, please add a `dd()` of the content of `$permission`, just as a sanity-check that the conditions needed to set that value to true do in fact exist.

Comment: I would return it after the foreach loop right?

Comment: You could actually do away with the `$hasPermission` variable altogether. Just `return true` inside the loop, right where you're otherwise assigning 'true'. And outside the loop, in the event that it gets that far, `return false`. Since you're not sure why the inside of the loop isn't being reached though, temporarily `dd($permission)` as the last line of the method so you can verify that it contains what you're expecting it to.

Comment: Can't seem to understand how to construct what you're saying but whatever it doesn't read inside the foreach. I'm using Laravel 8 btw.

Comment: $permission = json_decode( $user->role->permission);
foreach($permission as $p){
if($p->name ==$request->path()){
               if($p->name){
                return view('welcome');
 }
}
}
  return view('notFound');

Comment: i have directly return the welcome blade in the foreach however the notfond blade always returns .

Comment: this is my reference btw. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47JkN7QA0fs&list=PLKpfEl4N7tRqIx4VZmuZBnUQ6vG4uDgq7&index=31

Comment: I question the expertise behind this video. Aside from non-PSR2-compliant single-line control structures raising an eyebrow, this is actually use-case for [Policies and Guards](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization), or the `authorize()` method in a [Custom Request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#authorizing-form-requests), rather than rolling your own. That aside, what you have ought to work, so I suspect the problem is the data. Outside the foreach, add: `dd($permission, $path)`, and execute your route from a browser or Postman. Then edit your post to show us what's there.

Comment: so in short the one on youtube is a bad way of learning the ACL? it matches the path with the permission. yet it doesn't work. it really doesn't read the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

When it does't highlighted, it means you don't use that. If you change its value, it won't get highlighted. So, just return it to be used and get highlighted!

```
public function checkForPermission($user, $request)
{
    $permission = json_decode($user->role->permission);
    // echo $rolePermission[0]->name;
    // echo $request->path();
    $hasPermission = false;
    $path = $request->path();

    foreach ($permission as $p) {
        if ($p->name == $path) {
            if ($p->read) {
                $hasPermission = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $hasPermission;

}
```